# GOF class diagram for Builder pattern appears to contradict its corresponding sequence diagram

Tags: design-patterns, uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram, builder-pattern

In the *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object Oriented Software*, the Gang of Four present the following canonical form for the Builder pattern:

[image]

In Appendix B the following is mentioned regarding notation:

> Slanted type indicates that the class or operation is abstract
>
> An object reference representing a part-of or aggregation relationship is indicated by an arrowheaded line with a diamond at the base
>
> An arrowheaded line without the diamond denotes acquaintance (e.g., a `LineShape` keeps a reference to a `Color` object, which other shapes may share)

Martin Fowler's *UML Distilled* explains that composition is defined by two aspects:

- A composite should basically *own* its components. That is, deleting a `Polygon` object should ensure all of its `Points` get deleted as well.
- A composite should not share the objects it owns with other objects

Fowler uses the term "association" instead of "acquaintance". Regardless of which term is used, the idea of an associated object being shared by several other objects remains. Fowler goes on to state:

> Aggregation is strictly meaningless; as a result, I recommend that you ignore it in your own diagrams

If we maintain the terminology "part-of" and "acquaintance" from the Gang of Four, this is what we are left with:

- Part-of relationship:

  - Denoted by an arrowheaded line with a diamond at the base
  - `Point` is a part-of `Polygon` in the snippet below:

```
class Polygon
{
    private Point m_point;
    public Polygon()
    {
        m_point = new Point();
    }
}
```

- Acquaintance

  - Denoted by an arrowheaded line without a diamond at the base
  - In the following snippet, `LineShape` is acquainted with `Color`

```
class LineShape
{
    private Color m_color;
    public LineShape(Color color)
    {
        m_color = color;
    }
}
```

Now, the GOF's diagram for the Builder pattern shows a part-of relationship between the `Director` and the `Builder`. However, as shown by the sequence diagram below, they also have an independent `Client` create separate instances of a `Builder` and `Director`:

[image]

Because the `Client` must send requests to both a `Director` instance as well as a `ConcreteBuilder` instance, it would have to instantiate both separately as shown below:

```
ConcreteBuilder aConcreteBuilder = new ConcreteBuilder();
Director aDirector = new Director(aConcreteBuilder);
aDirector.Construct();
Product product = aConcreteBuilder.GetResult();
```

This would imply that `aConcreteBuilder` *can* outlive `aDirector` and thus that they have a part-of instead of acquaintance relationship.

Is this a mistake? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm a little rusty on class diagrams in UML but I recall an open diamond base meant the object can exist separate from the object.  A solid diamond base was for objects that live only as part of the parent.

Comment: To expand on what JimmyJames said, the solid or open diamond shape implies ownership of memory. The solid diamond means true composition: the memory allocated for one object is sufficient to hold all of the memory necessary for the "child" object. If memory for the "parent" object is reclaimed, the "child" object is also reclaimed. The open diamond implies one object holds a pointer to another object, and that both objects can live independently of one another.

Comment: After looking at the book, I think maybe the issue is the sloppy description of aggregation.  The description of association ("which other shapes may share") which follows directly gives the impression that aggregation children must not be shared, but that's not correct.   That's what is called a 'composition'.  I think that's what Fowler is getting at with "Aggregation is strictly meaningless" i.e.: it's just a multiplicity of associations.

Comment: @JimmyJames I'm sticking to GoF symbols here, in which there is no solid diamond, only open diamonds. The GoF symbology also happens to coincide with Fowler's book (and thus the broader UML standard). There are really only two distinct concepts: Ownership (no sharing, part-of, composition) and non-ownership (sharing, acquaintance, association). The presence of diamonds, whether filled or otherwise, seems only to denote ownership to both GOF *and* Fowler.

Comment: @user32882 I understand that but what I'm saying is that I don't see anywhere in the description of the diamond that it says the references *can't* be shared.  The following sentence which mentions sharing is about associations.  The fact that it follows directly does give the impression that aggregate references can't be shared but it doesn't actually say that.  Furthermore, they use the term 'aggregation' which is well-defined and allows for sharing of references.  Hence my assessment: sloppy.

Comment: To be fair, the book was released around the time UML was created.  Both the book and UML have been revised over the years and that could explain things.

Comment: @JimmyJames I disagree with your following statement: *I don't see anywhere in the description of the diamond that it says the references can't be shared.* Quoting from GOF: *An arrowheaded line without the diamond denotes acquaintance (e.g., a LineShape keeps a reference to a Color object, which other shapes may share)* basically implies that arrowheaded lines *with* a diamond means an object does *not* share its reference with other objects. This is consistent with Fowler's interpretation.

Comment: On page 22 of my copy it says "Aggregation implies that an aggregate object and it's owner have identical lifetimes."  The term 'implies' is a little weak but this would tend to agree with your assertion.  I therefore have to agree that the sequence diagram you point to is inconsistent with this definition.

Comment: It's not the standard definition of aggregation, however: ["Aggregation implies a relationship where the child can exist independently of the parent. Example: Class (parent) and Student (child). Delete the Class and the Students still exist."](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/uml-aggregation-vs-composition/).  Since they never mention 'composition', I think they are using the term 'aggregation' to include both contexts which might explain the exception you found.

Comment: @JimmyJames Exactly. Most sources will use "Aggregation" to refer to a a relationship where an object is shared by others, except for GoF who appear to use it to designate 
 the exact opposite. Fowler, due to this confusion, opts for throwing out the term altogether, which is a valid point. In any case, it looks like that class diagram is definitely wrong. Unfortunately, several places online have reproduced it (https://www.dofactory.com/net/builder-design-pattern#uml), which is a shame. I wish this stuff were more formalized and well-defined.

Comment: @user32882 That's one of many reasons why ancient books such as GoF are best left alone except for historical interest rather than treated as an informative source about modern software engineering - a great deal has changed in the meantime, and much of its content of questionable relevance in the modern world.    Software Engineering was a younger and immature discipline 20 years ago; indeed the way that the world relies upon and thinks about technology has evolved greatly.  Much of what might once have been conventional wisdom back then is often viewed as misguided or wrong today.

Comment: Just to show how subjective the shared aggregation is: in your example you explain that points are part of polygon. On the other side, a point may belong to several polygons. Moreover, a point could exist outside any polygon. What's the difference with a color of the polygon ?  For an artist the color of the shape is a part of that shape that is as important as the points themeselves.  What makes the point so special that it would deserve the diamond at the other end whereas the color not?

Comment: Forget about the meaning of the arrows - the whole point here is for a client to choose an appropriate concrete builder, and inject it into the the Director class (dependency injection). Therefore, the Director class is written against the interface of the Builder abstraction (the Director shouldn't know anything about the concrete builders).

Comment: But to answer your question, no, not an error. In UML (and its precursor in the book), all these relationships are *conceptual*. An object "owns" or is "responsible for" or "has the same lifetime as" some other object that represents its "part" is all meant to convey conceptual relationships. It's *not* a prescription telling you which language mechanisms to use, it does not require you to write the code so that these things are enforced by the compiler so that they are true at all times. It's enough that they are true in the way you use them, by design of how your code operates.

Comment: In other words, it doesn't matter that `aConcreteBuilder` can technically outlive the `aDirector`, it just matters that other code in the system doesn't see that, and that `aDirector` needs you to plug in a builder (plug in a "part" into the "whole") for it to operate. (It would be nice if you could enforce all these semantics via the compiler, but different languages have different expressive power, and not all of these conceptual relationships and constraints can be expressed entirely via language mechanisms.)

Comment: Also, read "Relating Run-Time and Compile-Time Structures" in Section 1.6 of Go4, specifically, the three paragraphs right under the figure, starting with "It's easy to confuse...". It basically says that the way the relationship is represented in source code (observed in isolation within the context of a single class), has little to do with the meaning of the arrows in the diagrams and the role of those objects in the patterns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GOF is pre-UML. It uses a variant of OMT, a notation invented by [J.Rumbaugh](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Rumbaugh), before it was merged into UML:

- The current UML terminology is "association".  OMT made a subtle difference between bidirectional "associations" (see footnote, GOF Annex B) and unidirectional "acquaintances" (implemented with reference).  In modern UML, both would be associations.  The  latter could be expressed with navigable associations, although UML is implementation neutral.
- Moreover, although OMT and earlier version of UML both used the white diamond, to represent part-whole relationships,
  J.Rumbaugh himself called this shared aggregation thing a "modeling placebo". Since UML 2.0, UML has kept the white diamond, but no longer defines any semantic for it. So, white diamond or no diamond, end up having the same semantic in UML, and the simpler notation should be preferred.

The white diamond, the so called shared aggregation, does not imply ownership of the elements at the other end (not in OMT and not in UML): elements can perfectly outlive their aggregate. The lifecycle limitation is  a characteristic of composition (more precisely, composite aggregation, which implies an exclusive ownership), which is represented with a black diamond.

---

##### Edit: additional information on OMT

To avoid any loss in translation, I acquired the legacy original OMT book.  Rumbaugh uses the terms "association" and "aggregation" (no "acquaintance") and confirms my previous conclusions:

> Aggregation is a special form of association, not an independent concept. (...) If the two objects are tightly bound by a part-whole relationship, it's an aggregation. If the two objects are usually considered as independent, even though they may be often linked, it is an association. (...)  **The decision to use aggregation is a matter of judgement and often arbitrary**. (...)

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like OMT and UML <2.0 used a white diamond to represent composition and no diamond to represent association. UML2.0 merges the two to represent association, and adds a new black diamond symbol to represent composition. Would that be correct? Also your answer doesn't address the class diagram for the Builder pattern. If OMT was used, then a white diamond would have represented composition back then. This is contradicted by the sequence diagram which clearly shows that the lifetime of the `Builder` must be independent from that of the `Director`. Is the class diagram wrong?

Comment: Not quite: UML had black diamond since the start to represent composition. The term compostion is btw ambiguous, as it may refer to composite aggregation, and [object composition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition). Object composition is one way to implement both aggregation and association.

Comment: Moreover, the part-of relation holding a reference to a part does not imply lifecycle management as composit aggregation in UML. They used this notation, as many (still) use aggregation in UML, and since the reference is injected at construction, the class diagram is correct with the semantics described